# How do I make a working menu in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I was using this code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
goto :Start

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof

:Start
:menu1
set /a select = 0
cls
call :ColorText 0a "Menu"
echo.
call :ColorText fb "Option1"
echo.
call :ColorText 0b "Option2"
echo.
call :ColorText 0b "Option3"
echo.
call :ColorText 0e "(W and S to scroll and Q to select)"
choice /c:wsq /n > nul
if errorlevel == w goto menu3
if errorlevel == s goto menu2
if errorlevel == q goto Option1
else goto menu1
:Option1
cls
echo This is Option1.
pause
goto Start
:menu2
set /a select = 0
cls
call :ColorText 0a "Menu"
echo.
call :ColorText 0b "Option1"
echo.
call :ColorText fb "Option2"
echo.
call :ColorText 0b "Option3"
echo.
call :ColorText 0e "(W and S to scroll and Q to select)"
choice /c:wsq /n > nul
if errorlevel w{
set /a select = 1
}
if errorlevel s{
set /a select = 3
}
if errorlevel q{
goto Option2
}
if %select%==1 goto menu1
if %select%==3 goto menu3
:menu3
set /a select = 0
cls
call :ColorText 0a "Menu"
echo.
call :ColorText 0b "Option1"
echo.
call :ColorText 0b "Option2"
echo.
call :ColorText fb "Option3"
echo.
call :ColorText 0e "(W and S to scroll and Q to select)"
choice /c:wsq /n > nul
if errorlevel w{
set /a select = 2
}
if errorlevel s{
set /a select = 1
}
if errorlevel q{
goto Option3
}
if %select%==1 goto menu1
if %select%==2 goto menu2
:Option2
cls
echo This is Option2.
pause
goto Start
:Option3
cls
echo This is Option3.
pause
goto Start
```

I keep getting an error when I go to use <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd>. It keeps skipping what it is suppose to go to and uses the code underneath it.

How would I make it so it will go to its actual label?

If possible, could I use the enter key and arrow keys in the command instead of <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd>?

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `choice /?`  Read the **Note** in the help file.

Comment: Also, brace the code with `( )`, not `{ }`.

Comment: `else goto menu1` is wrong syntax (type `if /?`), just put `goto menu1` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting idea!  **`:)`**  This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the array with options
set "n=0"
for %%a in (Option1 Option2 Option3) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "option[!n!]=%%a"
)

rem Define selected/unselected colors
set "selected=FB"
set "unselected=0B"

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "DEL=%%a"
goto :Start


:ColorText
<NUL set /P "=%DEL% " > "%~2"
findstr /V /A:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" NUL
del "%~2" > NUL 2>&1
exit /B


:Start
set /A "select=1, newSelect=1"
for /L %%i in (2,1,%n%) do set "color[%%i]=%unselected%"

:menu
set "color[%select%]=%unselected%"
set "select=%newSelect%"
set "color[%select%]=%selected%"
cls
call :ColorText 0A "Menu"
echo/
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
   call :ColorText !color[%%i]! "!option[%%i]!"
   echo/
)
call :ColorText 0E "(W and S to scroll and Q to select)"

:choice
choice /C:WSQ /N > NUL
goto Key-%errorlevel%

:Key-1  W = Up menu
if %select% equ 1 goto choice
set /A newSelect=select-1
goto menu

:Key-2  S = Down menu
if %select% equ %n% goto choice
set /A newSelect=select+1
goto menu

:Key-3  Q = Select current option
echo/
echo This is !option[%select%]!
pause
goto Start
```

Answer (score 2):

An `errorlevel` is always a numeric value !

The first `char` defined in `choice`(w in your case) will set the `errorlevel` as 1

The second `char` defined in `choice`(s in your case) will set the `errorlevel` as 2

...and so on...

so:

```
choice /c:wsq /n
if %errorlevel%==1 goto menu3
if %errorlevel%==2 goto menu2
if %errorlevel%==3 goto Option1
```